# Взаимодействие со сторонними файлами из приложения Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

Как мне из своего приложения (windows forms, c#) открыть, скажем, свойства файла в explorer'e? Или допустим скопировать, вырезать, вставить его?

Знаю, что открыть можно при помощи System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(), а вот с остальным беда.

P.s. я реализую свои, глобальные (для explorer'a в целом, а не для своего приложения), контекстные меню в семерке. и соответственно, в общем, проблема стоит в другом: в определении контекста и получении из него пунктов дефолтного меню. Если есть совет по реализации этого дела, ответ на первый вопрос - не актуален. Если нет, то я в качестве прототипа реализую это меню для конкретных файлов и папок с рабочего стола, для чего мне собственно и необходимо сделать кнопки "открыть", "вырезать", "копировать", "вставить" и "свойства".

Comment: [System.IO.File][1]

[System.IO.FileInfo][2]

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx


Comment: Зачем придумывать своё меню, если меню виндуса достраивается и это делается средствами реестра?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно не добавить пункты в меню, а изменить вид контекстных меню в принципе. 
Если Вам интересны подробности, то это проект по созданию интерфейса использующего Eye Tracking, т.е. интерфейса управления компьютером при помощи глаз.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону api винды, в противном случае это решение будет или своим аналогом или корявенькое. Или и то и другое 

Comment: Разумеется! WinAPI наше все! :)) без него и мышку не перехватишь. Это все уже давно готово.
Но вот с мышкой задача была в разы проще, чем с "контекстом"...

Но спасибо за совет.